# Printing a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWvKK.png)

```
Data - [DataFrame][1]
```

Hello there. I am a little newbie in python. I need to edit the dataset in the picture. But since there are 22 million lines and it is forcing my computer, I wanted to ask you before I tried it. I want to print X-Y-Z- "class" - "tahmin" columns from this data set (.csv file) to a new ".csv" file. Can you help with this?

I wish you healthy days :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/

```
import pandas as pd 
dataset = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
dataset = dataset[['X','Y','Z', 'class' , 'tahmin']]
dataset.to_csv('newFile.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is in your .csv file, but according to [this documentaion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), something like this should works:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    with open('newfile.csv', 'w') as newfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile)
        writer = csv.writer(newfile)
        writer.writerow(["X", "Y", "Z", "class", "tahmin"])
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should share some code i think, not all 22 million lines of course, but enough for us to know what we're working.

In the meantime, please refer to [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) explaining everything you need on reading/writing from cvs files in python.

just to clarify, the page is from the official python documentation website. Goodluck.